# How to join table with multiple rows in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in Postgres

**user**

| ID | name | group_a_id | group_b_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user_one | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | user_two | 3 | 4 |

**group**

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | group_one |
| 2 | group_two |
| 3 | group_three |
| 4 | group_four |

I am looking for a joined result but for 2 rows from the `group` table

Results

| ID | name | group_a_id | group_a_name | group_b_id | group_b_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user_one | 1 | group_one | 2 | group_two |
| 2 | user_two | 3 | group_three | 2 | group_four |

**So in one join query how to get the result ?**

`SELECT * from user,group WHERE user.group_a_id = group.id` like this how to join two rows from `group` to one with alias names `group_a_name, group_b_name`

Answer (score 0):

You want `join` . . . twice:

```
select u.*, g1.name, g2.name
from users u left join
     groups g1
     on g1.id = u.group_a_id left join
     groups g2
     on g2.id = u.group_b_id;
```